# Something wrong when getting data from text

Tags: php

I have a code in index.php:

```
<input type="text" name="login">
<input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submitBtn">
```

then

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents ("users.txt");
$data = explode("\n", $f);
$k = count($data);

for ($i=0; $i<$k; ++$i) {
    $user_array[$i] = explode (" | ", $data[$i]);
}
            
if (isset($_POST["submitBtn"])) {
    if ($_POST["password"] == $user_array[$i][1]) {
        echo "works";
    }
}
?>
```

This code should say "works" when password in POST matches with password in txt-file. But it does not.
If I match login with `$user_array[$i][0]` it works.

login and passwords are in txt-file saved like this:

```
login1 | pass1
login2 | pass2
```

And so on

Types are the same string, I checked it. It should be something I do not see.

Comment: Check the scope of your for-loop. You're checking the array values outside of it. Other than that I sincerely hope this is just a practice project for school or something because it is an **incredibly** bad idea to store users and passwords like this.

Comment: `file_get_contents` and `explode("\n"` can just be `file(`. Shouldn't you iterate over, explode then check index 1 for each item? The last item won't always be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be written much more efficiently:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submitBtn"])) {
  $login = $_POST["login"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];

  foreach (file("users.txt") as $line) {
    list($user, $pass) = explode(' | ', $line);
    if ($login === $user && $password === $pass) {
      echo 'Works';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Or, create a 'lookup' array (hashmap, dictionary, whatever you wanna call it):

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submitBtn"])) {
  foreach (file("users.txt") as $line) {
    list($user, $pass) = explode(' | ', $line);
    $logins[$user] = $pass;
  }

  $login = $_POST["login"];
  if (isset($logins[$login]) && $logins[$login] === $_POST["password"])
    echo 'Works';
}
```

**Other than that, this is just for demonstration purposes only!**

### DO NOT USE THIS IN ANYTHING CONNECTED TO THE INTERNET - IT IS HORRIBLY INSECURE!

I've tried to not overcomplicate the examples and keeping it readable at the same time; there's lots more things you can do.

Comment: I am just learning.

Answer (score 0):

`$i` is only in your loop. it's your iterator variable.

you may change your code like this:

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents ("users.txt");
$data = explode("\n", $f);
$login=[];
foreach($data as $item){    
     /*
      *   [ "login1" => "pass1" , "login2" => "pass2" ]
      */
    $array = explode (" | ", $item);
    $login[$array[0]] = $array[1];
}
            
if (isset($_POST["submitBtn"])) {
    // check if password is in array values!
    if (in_array($_POST["password"],$login)) {
        echo "works";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't need `in_array` when you can do the lookup just by checking if the key exists (`isset` or `arrray_key_exists` or...). This makes it [O(1) instead of O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: @RobIII we both know that what he is looking for it's not a good idea and it's not a good procedure at all! your idea can be done if he was checking it with "login" key! but according to the question, he is looking for a way to check password! he didn't mention anything about posting login key!

Comment: Then why store the usernames as keys at all? Why not put the passwords as key and do, again, an O(1) lookup with key_exists / isset? I think a little reading between the lines isn't a bad thing.

Comment: @RobIII I'm not arguing with you about it :)) i'm answering the question, based on what he said! I agree with you, without any notation, but we have to answer the questions based on them! if he mention anything about posting login, I would accept.

Comment: Just learning. Thank you!